# Remove Press any key to continue

Tags: windows, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

When I launch my .NET core 2.1 application from visual studio 2017 with Ctrl+F5, visual studio runs this command line:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c ""C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" exec "path\to\my.dll" & pause"
```

How can I remove `& pause` from there, i.e. suppress these “Press any key to continue . . .” prompts?

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting within Tools|Options|Debugging|General:

[image]

Not sure if this might have the desired affect for you - it certainly  works with Console apps in Visual Studio 2019.  Visual Studio 2017 has the 'Automatically close the console when debugging stops' option.

Comment: Can confirm it works when using the debugger. Unfortunately, doesn’t answer my question. When I press Ctrl+F5 that means “Start without debugging”, the setting has no effect. Thanks anyway.